# Combine CSS selectors with class not working

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I think I know the rules how to combine CSS selectors.

But it isn't working.

I have this CSS:

```
table,td
{
    border               : 1px solid #CCC;
    border-collapse      : collapse;
  font                 : small/1.5 "Tahoma", "Bitstream Vera Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table
{
    border                :none;
    border                :1px solid #CCC;
}
thead th,
tbody th
{
    background            : #fafafb;
  color                 : #666;  
    padding               : 5px 10px;
  border-left           : 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom            : 1px solid #CCC;
}
tbody th
{
  background            : #fafafb;
  border-top            : 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align            : left;
  font-weight           : normal;
}

#middletable {
  background            : #fafafb;
  border-top            : 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align            : center;
  font-weight           : normal;
}
tbody tr td
{
    padding               : 5px 10px;
  color                 : #666;
}
```

I want to specify it, so this rules are only working in one class.

So I put the class "greytable" to my table tag

```
<table class="greytable"></table>
```

After that I tried to put the selector to my CSS like this:

```
table.greytable, .greytable td
{
    border               : 1px solid #CCC;
    border-collapse      : collapse;
  font                 : small/1.5 "Tahoma", "Bitstream Vera Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table.greytable
{
    border                :none;
    border                :1px solid #CCC;
}
.greytable thead th,
.greytable tbody th
{
    background            : #fafafb;
  color                 : #666;  
    padding               : 5px 10px;
  border-left           : 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom            : 1px solid #CCC;
}
.greytable tbody th
{
  background            : #fafafb;
  border-top            : 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align            : left;
  font-weight           : normal;
}

#middletable {
  background            : #fafafb;
  border-top            : 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align            : center;
  font-weight           : normal;
}
.greytable tbody tr td
{
    padding               : 5px 10px;
  color                 : #666;
}
```

But it isn't working. Can anybody show me what did I do wrong and how it will work?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HYabQ/

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: `table.gerytable` - well for starters there's a typo there

Comment: and also on `.greytabel`

Comment: Thanks i found the typos too, but its still not working. (i fixed them in the post above) It dont work in this way: the table dont look like it should, and like it do if i dont use the class to specify

Comment: could you post a fiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HYabQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is pretty basic stuff. But I have created an example for you.

In this simple demo we have 2 tables, we only want to style the first one. We give it a `class` or `id` and using that give the table styles. Its the same as anything else really, as the table has the class `test` we don't need to try and get the table again e.g: `.test table` as we are already selecting it.

From this the first table with the class `test` will be styled, whereas the second will not be touched due to it not having class `test`.

Have a look at the fiddle and play around with it, hope this helps.

### HTML:

```
Only this one will be affected
<table class="test">
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

This table will not
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
.test th {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.test td {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/uUUq9/)

Comment: Thanks, thats what i know and do, and if i do it in JSfiddle it work fine. If i do it in the real webpage, it isnt working. I guess there is an other issue

Comment: I guess so, what sort of problems are you getting? Are all of the styles failing or?

Comment: Yes the style was failing, i copyed the whole code to an other page and back and now its working. rediculous -.-* Thanks to all

Comment: Very odd. Np, happy coding!